# Mutliple swift support dylibs in archived ipa package

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, archive, ipa

I recently did some work on reducing ipa package size of my iphone app, which contains code written in swift, objective-C, as well as C in the project. After archiving the ipa file, I noticed the file is a bit larger than expected. Therefore I unzipped the ipa files and found out there are duplicated swift support dylibs in the package.

The structure of the unzipped file is as below (well, useless files asides):

```
-Payload
     -....
     -Frameworks
          -libswiftCore.dylib
          -libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
          -libswiftDarwin.dylib
          -libswiftDispatch.dylib
          -libswiftFoundation.dylib
          -libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
          -libswiftSecurity.dylib
-SwiftSupport
     -libswiftCore.dylib
     -libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib
     -libswiftDarwin.dylib
     -libswiftDispatch.dylib
     -libswiftFoundation.dylib
     -libswiftObjectiveC.dylib
     -libswiftSecurity.dylib
```

Notice that the dylibs under SwiftSupport and Payload/Frameworks are the same swift support libs, and each of the folder occupies 2MB space, which are not compressable. But I checked the md5 of corresponding libs, the files with the same name are not the same file content.

So my question is, why it is required to have two copies of the dylibs in the final package. If avoidable, how to avoid to have redundant libs in the final package.

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem and I have no idea why :s

Comment: @Zalykr, yeah, it's weird.

Comment: and the problem is that the SwiftSupport folder is 55MB uncompressed which makes my app go above the 100MB mark that I'm trying to avoid!

Comment: @Zalykr, huh? No way, my swift support folder is only 2MB uncompressed. Maybe some other heavy feature you are relying on?

Comment: really? one of the files inside is libswiftCore.dylib which is 41.8 MB.. you don't have that one?

Comment: @Zalykr, nah, libswiftCore.dylib is about 6MB, but after compression the entire swift package is about 2MB. Not that big.

Comment: Do you mind telling me which architectures does your app support?

Comment: arm64, armv7, standard architecture.

Comment: @Zalykr I am having similar issue i see one file of 41.8 mb in swift support folder . Are you able to resolve this issue.

Comment: @androabhay, we found after the ipa was released in appstore, the ipa file is re-compressed and it's a lot smaller than the original ipa file that was uploaded to itunesconnect. So for now, I think the final size of the app can refer to the file size of adhoc, not the size that's archived for appstore submission. I assume the added swift support folder is for platform adaptation, but not included to the final distribution somehow.

Comment: Thats good. I have uploaded build waiting for review. Thank you JasonYang

Comment: @androabhay we had no luck with the size. It was still too big on the app store. Let me know if it works for you. Good luck!

Comment: Anyone found out why the archive is this big? The swift libs now have about 150Mb (300Mb doubled) so that is a lot to upload.